# R "requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments"

Tags: r, matrix

I intend to multiplicate two matrices. The math is pretty basic.

InputA represents a 8760x175 matrix and InputB a 175x1 matrix (rows x columns). So there should be no problem with the math...

However, even if I used the as.matrix command to save InputB, InputB is still saved as a character. All the transposing and re-transposing doesn't help either. I'm pretty clueless right now, it is simple on the paper, but I just can't get it to work in R Studio

```
 InputA <- as.matrix(Input_DE_2014_Bundeslaender_xml_EE_alpha[-1:-4,-1:-3])
 InputB <- as.matrix(Input_DE_2014_Bundeslaender_xml_EE_cap[-1:-2])
 InputB <- InputB[,-2:-4]
 InputB <- InputB[-1,]
 InputB <- InputB[,-2]
 NewMatr <- InputA %*% InputB
```

Comment: Impossible to help without a reproducible example. Maybe try `as.matrix(as.numeric(Input_DE_2014_Bundeslaender_xml_EE_alpha[-1:-4,-1:-3]))`

Comment: I will lay long odds that there are some columns of Input_DE_2014_Bundeslaender_xml_EE_cap that are factors, but appear to be numbers due to data entry difficulties. This is a common occurence when importing from Excel. Unfortunately Gilles has failed to offer a solution that will address this concern. I suggest you read R-FAQ 7.10

Comment: I second that emotion 42...